# MPDF 7.0 cannot register custom fonts

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, mpdf

I'm using MPDF to generate a PDF for something. I have to use the Tahoma font on it. MPDF is installed through composer and is on version 7+.

I use the following code:

```
$defaultConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

$defaultFontConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'mode' => 'en',
    'default_font_size' => 10,
    'margin_left' => 9.5,
    'margin_right' => 0,
    'margin_top' => 42.5,
    'margin_bottom' => 0,
    'margin_header' => 7.1,
    'margin_footer' => 2,
    'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [__DIR__ . '/customFontsMPDF']),
    'fontData' => $fontData + [
       'tahoma' => [
           'R' => 'tahoma.ttf',
           'B' => 'tahomabd.ttf'
       ]
    ]
]);
```

And I type this in order to add the CSS:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<style>' . file_get_contents('css.css') . '</style>');
```

The css contains the following rule:

```
body {
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
```

Somehow, the font doesn't work and it will be the default DejaVuSansCondensed font (I know for sure since I saw it in Acrobat Reader)

I do have a folder called customFontsMPDF in my current working directory (**DIR**) and it contains the tahoma.ttf and tahomabd.ttf files. What am I doing wrong and why doesn't it work, and how can I get it working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct configuration key is `fontdata` not `fontData` – note the lower case "d".

Comment: Oh wow... it was this simple. Thanks! You solved my problem :)

Comment: Still not working? Currently, you really must append the arrays => you must first get defaults and merge it with yours and set that => your simple config is NOT enaugh, use as OP showed (except the wrong fontdata spelling of course...)